# What criteria were used to set the "useme" flag in the NOMAD astrometric catalog?

Tags: astronomy

How was the value of the "useme" flag in the [NOMAD](http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/icas/usno-icas) astrometric catalog set? The [readme](http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/nomad/nomad-readme-file) just describes the field as "Recommended astrometric standard," but says nothing about the basis on which that recommendation was made.

Answer (score 3):

It seem to be a difficult thing to track down, but perhaps the [recommended catalog descriptions](http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/information/catalog-info/catalog-information-center-1#nomad) on the USNO site can offer some explanation. I couldn't find something that directly gave the methods used to determine whether or not to set the `useme` flag, but looking at the NOMAD recommended ordering of different catalog data, as well as the catalog descriptions themselves, might give more insight on this.